# Неверная передача данных в запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется запрос вот такого вида:

```
SELECT t1.va, t1.vv, sss.id
FROM (SELECT
    technological_map, JSON_EXTRACT(rpd.technological_map, '$[0].current[*].valuation-tools') as va,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(json_extract(JSON_EXTRACT(rpd.technological_map, '$[0].current[*].valuation-tools'), "$[*]"), "[", ""), "]", ""), '"', '') as vv
      FROM `rpd`
      WHERE id = 1395) as t1, spr_valuation_tools as sss
WHERE sss.id IN (t1.vv)
```

К сожалению, отдаёт он не все данные. В столбце `t1.vv` должно быть 4 значения (перечисление id) раньше были просто строкой, в запросе парсим, но в `WHERE sss.id IN (t1.vv)` строка с перечислением воспринимается как double. Тем самым вместо 4 строк, я получая 1

Как поменять запрос, чтобы он корректно отрабатывал?

Comment: Нужны данные, которые находятся у вас в таблицах. Вы отдельно смотрели на подзапрос, он нужные значения возвращает?

Comment: @SwaD, да подзапрос выдаёт правильно. Только мне теперь полученную строку ```t1.vv``` надо как-то сделать массивом, чтобы в IN передать.

От подзапроса получаем строку вида "1, 10, 13, 14"

Comment: *От подзапроса получаем строку вида "1, 10, 13, 14"* Вот именно так, с пробелами после запятых? Убери эти пробелы нахрен, и тогда ```WHERE FIND_IN_SET(sss.id, t1.vv)```.

Comment: @Akina, вы ж мой спаситель. Спасибо. Всё отработало, как надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользователь [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina) дал верное решение:

> От подзапроса получаем строку вида "1, 10, 13, 14" Вот именно так, с пробелами после запятых? Убери эти пробелы нахрен, и тогда `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(sss.id, t1.vv)`